# VIsualForce Page which populates a Field

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have an object called `Sales_and_Marketing__c`, and I would like to override the standard <kbd>New</kbd> button so that the field `Sales_Contact__c` (lookup to `Contact`) gets pre populated with the logged in `User`.

On the `User` object we have a field `ContactId__c`. This field is a of a data type of Text(18) and just holds the contact id.

I have looked on online for scenarios and have attempted to write this but i am a little confused and appreciate some help

Apex class :

```
public with sharing class NewMKtMaterialsRequest

{
    public Contact profileInfo {get;set;}
    public NewMKtMaterialsRequest(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    //public NewMKtMaterialsRequest() 
{
        Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        List<User> UserList = [select U.ContactId from User U where Id =: userId];
        Id contactId = UserList.get(0).ContactId;
//Contact profileInfo = [SELECT ID FROM Contact WHERE Id =: contactId LIMIT 1];

        Contact profileInfo = [SELECT 
            Id, 
            FirstName, 
            User__c, 
            User__r.Id, 
            User__r.Name 
        FROM Contact WHERE Id =: contactId LIMIT 1];

  }
public PageReference RedirectToMKTRequest()
    {
        return new PageReference('/a0R/e?Sales_Contact__c=contactId.id&nooverride=1');
  }
}
```

Visual Force Page ;

```
  <apex:page standardController="sales_and_marketing__c" extensions="NewMKtMaterialsRequest" action="{!RedirectToMKTRequest}">

        </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create `PageReference` instance and put the parameters like this:

```
public PageReference RedirectToMKTRequest()
{
    PageReference pg = controller.edit();
    pg.getParameters().put('Sales_Contact__c', contactId);
    pg.getParameters().put('nooverride', '1');
    pg.setRedirect(true);
    return pg;
}
```

Comment: how can i pursue this avenue ?

Comment: @Masond3, Replace `Sales_Contact__c` with `CF00N61000008ZRki` in this code, the prepopulation would then work.

Comment: @rahual - i get the following error 
List has no rows for assignment to SObject 
An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

Comment: @Masond3, you should always check the list before accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, I think I see the issue in here. The PageRef you're building:

```
return new PageReference('/a0R/e?Sales_Contact__c=contactId.id&nooverride=1');
```

You have the 'Sales_Contact__c=contactId.id' part, but it's inside quotes, meaning it will literally append the literal text 'contactId.id' in the URL.

Try this:

```
return new PageReference('/a0R/e?Sales_Contact__c=' + profileInfo.Id + '&nooverride=1');
```

Comment: @Dominator_101- if i include your logic i get the following error "Variable does not exist: contactId.id"

Comment: @Masond3 Sorry, I didn't pay attention to your other variable names. Try this instead of contactId.id (I'll update the post): profileInfo.Id

Comment: That allowed me to save. Within my VisualForce page i need to include the field i am passing the value dont i ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean...BUt after a quick check, it looks like to pre-pop stuff on an edit page you might need to use the field's Id, not it's API name. To get that, go to the object's fields, click on the field you want to populate, then take the Id out of the URL. You'll also need to put 'CF' in the front of the Id. For example, say the field Id is '00N61000008ZRki', you'll need to put 'CF00N61000008ZRki=' instead of 'Sales_Contact__c='.