# VisualForce Page : Userinfo.getUserId(); No matching users found

Tags: apex, visualforce, user

I have an object called Sales_and_Marketing__c, and I would like to override the standard New button so that the field Sales_Contact_New__c(lookup to user object) gets pre populated with the logged in  User.

I have looked on online for scenarios and have attempted to write this however i am getting the following error (see screen shot attached)

**Apex class :**

```
public with sharing class Extension1 {

public final sales_and_marketing__c objX;
public Extension1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 

    {
        this.objX = (sales_and_marketing__c)controller.getRecord();
        objX.Sales_Contact_New__c= Userinfo.getUserId();     
    }

public PageReference RedirectToMKTRequest()
  {
return new PageReference ('/a0R/e?CF00N6E000000UdP0=' + objX.Sales_Contact_New__c + '&nooverride=1');

//return new PageReference ('/a0R/e?CF00N6E000000UdP0=' + objX.Sales_Contact_New__c + '&nooverride=1');
 }
}
```

**Visual Force page**

```
<apex:page standardController="sales_and_marketing__c" extensions="Extension1" action="{!RedirectToMKTRequest}">

        </apex:page>
```

This is the error I am presented with:

[image: No matching users found.]

> No matching users found.

Comment: Because it is considering it as string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pre-populate the lookup field through URL, If field's HTML Id is CF00N6E000000UdP0.

Two parameters needs to be passed:

1. Lookup Value :

   - This you can pass with `CF00N6E000000UdP0`
2. Lookup Id:

   - This can be passed with `CF00N6E000000UdP0`**_lkid**

Try this example:

```
public PageReference RedirectToMKTRequest() {

    User objUser = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User 
        WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

    return new PageReference('/a0R/e?CF00N6E000000UdP0=' + objUser.Name + 
        '&CF00N6E000000UdP0_lkid=' + objUser.Id +
        '&nooverride=1');
}
```

Refer this blog for more details- [Salesforce URL Hacking to Prepopulate Fields on a Standard Page Layout](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html)

Comment: Hi Rahul, 
if i go with your method i would return the following error in the ;

Daniel MasonCF00N6E000000UdP0=00558000001PjR8AAK

there it would need to be something like this ; 

    
public PageReference RedirectToMKTRequest()
 {
    User objUser = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

return new PageReference ('/a0R/e?CF00N6E000000UdP0=' + objUser.Name  +'&nooverride=1');
}
 }

Comment: I missed a ampersand sign, updated the answer

Comment: Thanks @rahul sharma - I been looking at this all morning and you have come along and helped straight away :) i have a similar request here however this is a contact, could you have a quick browse at this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165957/visualforce-page-which-populates-a-field

Comment: Cheers @Masond3, Posted comment in one of the answer of the mentioned question.